# what RP means in Url Rewrite Management options column

Tags: magento-1.9, url, url-rewrite

I look at the Url Rewrite Management for custom URL rewrite and found that there are RP in option column. What is the difference between RP and non RP custom option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RP means it's a Permanent Redirect (301). It's one of the options in the "Redirect" field dropdown list on the Edit page.